# Angularjs - connection with included model and filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an issue with my included html. I've got main HTML, where I've got ng-repeat with filter like this:

```
 <tr class="pointer" ng-repeat="plan in filtr = (plans | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchSurname)">
```

And above this code, I've included filter html:

```
<div ng-include="filterList"></div>
```

In this file I've got input with ng-model:

```
    <input ng-show="$state.includes('state.to.go')" id="surname" type="text" class="form-control" 
    ng-model="searchSurname" placeholder="Filter surname">
```

Include creates new child scope, but I don't exactly know how to fix it.

Have I change something in controller of my main html?

Comment: have you tried `ng-model="$parent.searchSurname"` ?

Comment: Oh damn, thank you very much.. thats it...